# Should I use instance or class attributes if there will only be one instance?

Tags: python, class, variables, static, member

I have Python classes, of which I need only one instance at runtime, so it would be sufficient to have the attributes only once per class and not per instance. If there would be more than one instance (which won't happen), all instance should have the same configuration. I wonder which of the following options would be better or more "idiomatic" Python.

Class variables:

```
class MyController(Controller):

  path = "something/"
  children = [AController, BController]

  def action(self, request):
    pass
```

Instance variables:

```
class MyController(Controller):

  def __init__(self):
    self.path = "something/"
    self.children = [AController, BController]

  def action(self, request):
    pass
```

Answer (score 177, accepted):

If you have only one instance anyway, it's best to make all variables per-instance, simply because they will be accessed (a little bit) faster (one less level of "lookup" due to the "inheritance" from class to instance), and there are no downsides to weigh against this small advantage.

Comment: Never heard of the Borg pattern? Only having one instance was the wrong way to have it in the first place.

Comment: @Devin, yep, I've heard of the Borg pattern, since I'm the one who introduced it (in 2001, cfr http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66531-singleton-we-dont-need-no-stinkin-singleton-the-bo/ ;-).  But there's nothing wrong, in simple cases, with simply having a single instance with no enforcement.

Comment: @user1767754, easy to make them yourself with `python -mtimeit` -- but having just done so in python3.4 I note that accessing an `int` class variable is actually about 5 to 11 nanoseconds *faster* than the same as instance variable on my old workstation -- not sure what codepath makes it so.

Answer (score 49):

Further echoing [Mike's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/192839/mike-graham) and [Alex's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95810/alex-martelli) advice and adding my own color...

Using instance attributes are the typical... the more idiomatic Python. Class attributes are not used used as much, since their use cases are specific. The same is true for static and class methods vs. "normal" methods. They're special constructs addressing specific use cases, else it's code created by an aberrant programmer wanting to show off they know some obscure corner of Python programming.

Alex mentions in his reply that access will be (a little bit) faster due to one less level of lookup... let me further clarify for those who don't know about how this works yet. It is very similar to variable access -- the search order of which is:

1. locals
2. nonlocals
3. globals
4. built-ins

For attribute access, the order is:

1. instance
2. class
3. base classes as determined by the [MRO](http://python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro) (method resolution order)

Both techniques work in an "inside-out" manner, meaning the most local objects are checked first, then outer layers are checked in succession.

In your example above, let's say you're looking up the `path` attribute. When it encounters a reference like "`self.path`", Python will look at the instance attributes first for a match. When that fails, it checks the class from which the object was instantiated from. Finally, it will search the base classes. As Alex stated, if your attribute is found in the instance, it doesn't need to look elsewhere, hence your little bit of time savings.

However, if you insist on class attributes, you need that extra lookup. *Or*, your other alternative is to refer to the object via the class instead of the instance, e.g., `MyController.path` instead of `self.path`. That's a direct lookup which will get around the deferred lookup, but as alex mentions below, it's a global variable, so you lose that bit that you thought you were going to save (unless you create a local reference to the [global] class name).

The bottom-line is that you should use instance attributes most of the time. However, there will be occasions where a class attribute is the right tool for the job. Code using both at the same time will require the most diligence, because using `self` will only get you the instance attribute object and *shadows* access to the class attribute of the same name. In this case, you *must* use access the attribute by the class name in order to reference it.

Comment: @wescpy, but `MyController` is looked up in the globals, so the total cost is higher than `self.path` where `path` is an instance variable (since `self` is _local_ to the method == super-fast lookup).

Comment: ah, true. good catch. i guess the only workaround is to create a local reference... at this point, it's not really worth it.

Answer (score 28):

When in doubt, you probably want an instance attribute.

Class attributes are best reserved for special cases where they make sense. The only very-common use case is methods. It isn't *uncommon* to use class attributes for read-only constants that instances need to know (though the only benefit to this is if you also want access from *outside* the class), but you should certainly be cautious about storing any state in them, which is seldom what you want. Even if you will only have one instance, you should write the class like you would any other, which usually means using instance attributes.

Comment: The class variables are a kind of read-only constants. If Python let me define constants, I would have written it as constants.

Comment: @deamon, I am slightly more likely to put my constants completely outside of a class definitions and name them in all caps. Putting them inside the class is fine too. Making them instance attributes won't hurt anything, but might be a bit odd. I don't think this is an issue where the community gets behind one of the options too much.

Comment: @MikeGraham FWIW, [Google's Python Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html?showone=Global_variables#Global_variables) suggests to avoid global variables in favor of class variables. There are exceptions though.

Comment: Here is a new link to [Google's Python Style Guide](https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/pyguide.md). Now there is simply written: `avoid global variables` and their definition is, that global variables are also variables that are declared as class attributes. However, Python's own style guide ([PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)) should be the first place to go for questions of this kind. Then your own mind should be the tool of choice (of course you can also get ideas from Google, for example).

Answer (score 8):

Same question at [Performance of accessing class variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703605/performance-of-accessing-class-variables-in-python/) - the code here adapted from @Edward Loper

Local Variables are the fastest to access, pretty much tied with Module Variables, followed by Class Variables, followed by Instance Variables.

There are 4 scopes you can access variables from:

1. Instance Variables (self.varname)
2. Class Variables (Classname.varname)
3. Module Variables (VARNAME)
4. Local Variables (varname)

The test:

```
import timeit

setup='''
XGLOBAL= 5
class A:
    xclass = 5
    def __init__(self):
        self.xinstance = 5
    def f1(self):
        xlocal = 5
        x = self.xinstance
    def f2(self):
        xlocal = 5
        x = A.xclass
    def f3(self):
        xlocal = 5
        x = XGLOBAL
    def f4(self):
        xlocal = 5
        x = xlocal
a = A()
'''
print('access via instance variable: %.3f' % timeit.timeit('a.f1()', setup=setup, number=300000000) )
print('access via class variable: %.3f' % timeit.timeit('a.f2()', setup=setup, number=300000000) )
print('access via module variable: %.3f' % timeit.timeit('a.f3()', setup=setup, number=300000000) )
print('access via local variable: %.3f' % timeit.timeit('a.f4()', setup=setup, number=300000000) )
```

The result:

```
access via instance variable: 93.456
access via class variable: 82.169
access via module variable: 72.634
access via local variable: 72.199
```