# Python value/reference/I don't even know

Tags: python, algorithm, 2d

I've tried to implement the diamond-square algorithm in python, but I seem to be bogged down in the workings of the language... I have a 'quad' class that has 9 2D (custom) points inside it:

- top left
- top right
- top middle
- bottom left
- bottom right
- bottom middle
- left middle
- centre
- right middle

These 9 are held in a dictionary.

There are also 4 'child' quads in a dictionary for every quad.

- top left
- top right
- bottom left
- bottom right

The problem I have is that when I create the child quads for a quad, they mess up the fields of the parent's 2D points, and I have no idea why.

Source code (Python 3.2): http://pastebin.com/5Ywz4anY

Comment: I'm inclined to call this a duplicate of [Python: Difference between class and instance attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/207000/395760) (I hastily voted so). Of course the question *asked* is different, but the underlying difference is exactly the same and is so commonplace...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a Python expert, but I believe you need to define the Points and Children variables inside the init method if you want them to be instance variables.  As it stands now, I think all instances would share the same dictionaries.

See http://legacy.python.org/doc/essays/ppt/acm-ws/sld051.htm

Another example: [Instance variables vs. class variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714573/instance-variables-vs-class-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Stop using a dictionary. Define these points as members within your `__init__` method:

```
self.ne = TR
```

(etc)