# Python... Static variables?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Instance variables vs. class variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714573/instance-variables-vs-class-variables-in-python)

What is the difference between these two situations and how is it treated with in Python?

Ex1

```
class MyClass:
     anArray = {}
```

Ex2

```
class MyClass:
     __init__(self):
          self.anArray = {}
```

It seems like the in the first example the array is being treated like a static variable. How does Python treat this and what is the reason for this?

Comment: It's not a "static variable", but it is a member of a *specific object* which that has a "stable name". Which object might that be? ;-) (Remember, classes are not "just definitions" in Python.)

Comment: They're called class variables. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714573/instance-variables-vs-class-variables-in-python or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first example, `anArray` (which in Python is called a dictionary, not an array) is a class attribute. It can be accessed using `MyClass.anArray`. It exists as soon as the class is defined.

In the second example, `anArray` is an instance attribute. It can be accessed using `MyClass().anArray`. (But note that doing that just throws away the `MyClass` instance created; a more sensible example is `mc = MyClass(); mc.anArray['a'] = 5`.) It doesn't exist until an instance of the class is created.

Answer (score 0):

It is declared diffrent area. 
Ex1 is Like global or static variable.

```
obj = MyClass()
obj2 = MyClass()
print "IS one instance ", id(obj.anArray) == id(obj2.anArray)
```

Ex2 is local attribute.

```
obj = MyClass()
obj2 = MyClass()
print "IS one instance ", id(obj.anArray) == id(obj2.anArray)
```

Comment: I think class attribute and instance attribute are more appropriate terms.

Comment: Im not sure what you're trying to show with those bits of code, as they're exactly identical..

Comment: For anyone wondering, the first print statement will return True and the second will return False