# Python class variable access speed

Tags: python, performance, class, variables

Say there is a class:

```
class x(obj):
    y = 1
```

What is faster (or preferred):

```
    def __init__(self):
        print self.y
```

or:

```
    def __init__(self):
        print x.y
```

I assume `x.y` better communicates the intend but I'm interested in the speed implications.

Comment: Why don't you just measure it?  The `timeit` module is your friend.  My guess is that the latter version is faster, since it will skip the instance look-up, but the difference is probably small.  Go for the semantics you need, unless you *really* need the performance.

Comment: In the grand scheme of things that can affect the speed of your code, wondering about access "speed" of class variables is way down the list; if on it at all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714573/instance-variables-vs-class-variables-in-python/52777427#52777427 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703605/performance-of-accessing-class-variables-in-python/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The performance gain you could possibly achieve with these micro optimizations doesn't matter. The impact of the `print`ing dwarfs the cost of attribute access by far. For reference, here's a test script:

```
import sys,timeit
class ClassAccess(object):
    y = 1
    def __init__(self):
        print(ClassAccess.y)

class SelfAccess(object):
    y = 1
    def __init__(self):
        print(self.y)

ca = timeit.timeit(ClassAccess, number=100000)
sa = timeit.timeit(SelfAccess, number=100000)

sys.stderr.write(str(ca) + "\n")
sys.stderr.write(str(sa) + "\n")
```

On my machine (with the yakuake terminal), this outputs

```
0.640013933182
0.628859043121
```

This is within experimental error of both variants being identical. Crude experimentation shows that:

- Approximately 90% of the runtime is caused by actually displaying the printed result.
- Of the rest, approximately 50% is the time that the print statement alone takes up.
- Approximately 80% of the rest of *that* is caused by the allocation of the objects.

Therefore, it's safe to say to derive the conclusion that there is no difference in performance.

Comment: If I replace `print` with 'z =', the first one is slightly faster. Thanks.

Comment: It __does__ matter. Not in terms in performance, but `self.y` __is__ the preferred method. It's easier to maintain (if the class name changes no need to change all functions), and it allows overriding of the class-wide value if needed.

Comment: @Ecir Hana: oh and let's not forget overriding through inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Note that depending on the class implementation the returned values may differ.

This returns the y attribute of the instance :

```
def __init__(self):
    print self.y
```

While this returns the y attribute of the class :

```
def __init__(self):
    print x.y
```

If the constructor override the y attribute a la :

```
def __init__(self, y=None):
    self.y = y
def print(self):
    print self.y
```

the returned values will differ.
Python looks up the instance internal dictionary checking for y before to check for the class internat dictionary.
So I think that print x.y should be slightly faster because it avoids looking up the instance dictionary.