# How would I access variables from one class to another?

Tags: python, class, variables

I am writing a program that is utilizing multiple classes.  I have one class that is dedicated to determining values for a set of variables.  I would then like to be able to access the values of those variables with other classes.  My code looks as follows:

```
class ClassA(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 1
        self.var2 = 2

    def methodA(self):
        self.var1 = self.var1 + self.var2
        return self.var1


class ClassB(ClassA):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = ?
        self.var2 = ?

object1 = ClassA()
sum = object1.methodA()
print sum
```

I use classA to initialize 2 variables (var1 and var2).  I then use methodA to add them, saving the result as var1 (I think this will make var1 = 3 and var2 = 2).  What I want to know is how would I have ClassB then be able to get the values for var1 and var2 from ClassA?

Comment: What if you want the ClassB we one of the attributes of classA?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

`var1` and `var2` are [instance variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714573/instance-variables-vs-class-variables-in-python). That means that you have to send the instance of `ClassA` to `ClassB` in order for ClassB to access it, i.e:

```
class ClassA(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 1
        self.var2 = 2

    def methodA(self):
        self.var1 = self.var1 + self.var2
        return self.var1



class ClassB(ClassA):
    def __init__(self, class_a):
        self.var1 = class_a.var1
        self.var2 = class_a.var2

object1 = ClassA()
sum = object1.methodA()
object2 = ClassB(object1)
print sum
```

On the other hand - if you were to use [class variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714573/instance-variables-vs-class-variables-in-python), you could access var1 and var2 without sending object1 as a parameter to ClassB.

```
class ClassA(object):
    var1 = 0
    var2 = 0
    def __init__(self):
        ClassA.var1 = 1
        ClassA.var2 = 2

    def methodA(self):
        ClassA.var1 = ClassA.var1 + ClassA.var2
        return ClassA.var1



class ClassB(ClassA):
    def __init__(self):
        print ClassA.var1
        print ClassA.var2

object1 = ClassA()
sum = object1.methodA()
object2 = ClassB()
print sum
```

Note, however, that class variables are shared among all instances of its class.

Comment: How can I run the above code and do the same thing without this part: ```object1 = ClassA()
sum = object1.methodA()
object2 = ClassB()
print sum``` ??

Answer (score 12):

Can you explain *why* you want to do this?

You're playing around with *instance variables/attributes* which won't migrate from one class to another (they're bound not even to `ClassA`, but to a particular *instance* of `ClassA` that you created when you wrote `ClassA()`).  If you want to have changes in one class show up in another, you *can* use class variables:

```
class ClassA(object):
   var1 = 1
   var2 = 2
   @classmethod
   def method(cls):
       cls.var1 = cls.var1 + cls.var2
       return cls.var1
```

In this scenario, `ClassB` will pick up the values on `ClassA` from inheritance.  You can then access the class variables via `ClassA.var1`, `ClassB.var1` or even from an instance `ClassA().var1` (provided that you haven't added an instance method `var1` which will be resolved before the class variable in attribute lookup.

I'd have to know a little bit more about your particular use case before I know if this is a course of action that I would actually recommend though...

Comment: I am just doing it for practice really.  I am trying to teach myself, and when working with classes this was a question that I had.  I searched around, and couldn't really understand the other answers.  Figured I'd give it a shot to ask.  I think I have the hang of it now!  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

var1 and var2 is an Instance variables of **ClassA**. Create an Instance of ClassB and when calling the methodA it will check the methodA in Child class (**ClassB**) first, If methodA is not present in **ClassB** you need to invoke the **ClassA** by using the **[super() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/what-does-super-do-in-python)** which will get you all the methods implemented in **ClassA**. Now, you can access all the methods and attributes of ClassB.

```
class ClassA(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 1
        self.var2 = 2

    def methodA(self):
        self.var1 = self.var1 + self.var2
        return self.var1


class ClassB(ClassA):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("var1",self.var1)
        print("var2",self.var2)


object1 = ClassB()
sum = object1.methodA()
print(sum)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note you are answering a very old and already answered question. Here is a guide on [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

we can access/pass arguments/variables from one class to another class using object reference.

```
#Class1
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 10
        self.b = 20
        self.add = 0

    def calc(self):
        self.add = self.a+self.b

#Class 2
class Test2:
    def display(self):
        print('adding of two numbers: ',self.add)
#creating object for Class1
obj = Test()
#invoking calc method()
obj.calc()
#passing class1 object to class2
Test2.display(obj)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just create the variables in a class. And then inherit from that class to access its variables. But before accessing them, the parent class has to be called to initiate the variables.

```
class a:
    def func1(self):
        a.var1 = "Stack "

class b:
    def func2(self):
        b.var2 = "Overflow"

class c(a,b):
    def func3(self):
        c.var3 = a.var1 + b.var2
        print(c.var3)

a().func1()
b().func2()
c().func3()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class ClassA(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 1
        self.var2 = 2
    def method(self):
        self.var1 = self.var1 + self.var2
        return self.var1

class ClassB(ClassA):
    def __init__(self):
        ClassA.__init__(self)

object1 = ClassA() 
sum = object1.method()  
object2 = ClassB() 
print sum
```