# Cant access instance variable from another class

Tags: python-3.x

I have checked many questions replied here, but can't access an instance variable from another class(I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19993795/how-would-i-access-variables-from-one-class-to-another) as example)

```
#in file: view.py
class treeview():
    def __init__(self):
        ....(no mention of row_num)
    def viewer(self, booklist, act=-1):
        row_num = len(treeview().full_list)
        print(row_num)   # prints the correct value, which is > 0
        return row_num

#in main file 
class Window(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):
    def __init__(self, application, giofile=None):
        self.TreeView = view.treeview()
    def extract_data_from_cr(self, select_button):
        print(self.TreeView.row_num)
```

Gives error:

```
   AttributeError: 'treeview' object has no attribute 'row_num'
```

If I try to add `row_num` inside treeview() as:

```
class treeview():
    def __init__(self):
        self.row_num = 0
    def viewer(self, booklist, act=-1):
        self.row_num = len(treeview().full_list)
        print(self.row_num)
        # return row_num
```

then, `print(self.TreeView.row_num)` in `main` always yields `0`.

I cant find whats going wrong here.Kindly help.

**After Mitch's comment**
if I define row_num without calling treeview() again as:

```
class treeview():
    def __init__(self):
        self.row_num = 0
    def viewer(self, booklist, act=-1):
        self.row_num = len(self.bookstore)
        print(type(self.bookstore))  # <class 'gi.overrides.Gtk.ListStore'>

        print(self.row_num) # 5 (expected for a particular case)
```

Now, when calling the `def extract_data_from_cr`, I am expecting this number:

```
def extract_data_from_cr(self, select_button):
    print(self.TreeView.row_num)   #is giving 0
```

**A MCVE**

```
$cat mcve.py 
class classA():
    def __init__(self):
        self.row_num = 0
        print("HiA")
    def define(self):
        la = ["A", "B", "C"]
        self.row_num = len(la)
        print(self.row_num)  #prints 3 when get called from mcve2
        return(self.row_num)
classA().define()
```

and

```
$cat mcve2.py 
#!/usr/bin/python
import mcve

class classB():
    def get_val(self):
        self.MCVE = mcve.classA()
        print("Hi2")
        print(self.MCVE.row_num) #prints 0

classB().get_val()
```

Result:

```
 python3 mcve2.py 
HiA
3
HiA
Hi2
0
```

I know. if I call `ClassA.define()` explicitely from `ClassB.get_val()`, I will get the desired value. But I am looking for transfaring the value it got (`Result: line 2`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*<sup>Working from your edited MCVE:</sup>*

When you set `self.MCVE = classA()` in the `get_val` method, you are setting `MCVE` to be a *new instance* of `classA`. Hence, any modifications to the `row_num` attribute of some other instance of `classA` are irrelevant.

<sup>e.g.</sup> `classA().define()` is modifying the `row_num` attribute for an entirely different class instance. Its `row_num` is an instance variable which is only defined for *that particular instance*.

Should you want the `row_num` attribute to persist across all `classA` instances, you would want to set it as a class variable, like so (bit of a nonsensical example though).

```
class classA():
    row_num = 0

    def __init__(self):
        print("HiA")
    def define(self):
        la = ["A", "B", "C"]
        classA.row_num = len(la)
        print(classA.row_num)  #prints 3 when get called from mcve2
        return classA.row_num
classA().define()

class classB():
    def get_val(self):
        self.MCVE = classA()
        print("Hi2")
        print(self.MCVE.row_num) #prints 0

classB().get_val()
```

**Outputs**:

```
HiA
3
HiA
Hi2
3
```

You otherwise may be looking to use a `property`, which could be set in the `__init__` of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You never declared row_num in the class. You probably meant to do

```
class treeview():
    def __init__(self):
        ....(no mention of row_num)
    def viewer(self, booklist, act=-1):
        self.row_num = len(treeview().full_list)
        print(self.row_num)   # prints the correct value
        return self.row_num
```

Which then works again fine.

Comment: My fault. actually in my 2nd example after `If I try to add row_num` line, I have added it inside `treeview()`, which always yields 0, when called from `main`. Example is edited. Please have a look.