# How to call specific attributes from another class(PYTHON)

Tags: python

[Im working on the rental class now .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjL8T.png)

[image]

[The rental class is needed for the rental object which has attributes from the other classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yk0m.png)

[image]

I am trying to initialize the other attributes by using super.init

Is this correct, please advise.Using python 3.5

Comment: Please include your code, sample input, and desired output in the text of the question. See [MCVE].

Comment: paste your code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

No, You don't need to initialise always. A class is initialized once by super.init. If you need to access the attributes from one class to another class do one thing make them available on the main thread i.e by using (self. "attribute"). As you know in Python every class works on the separate thread. So basically you need to make that attribute available on the main thread and then call that.

For eg here's a code snippet for multithreading I wrote.

```
class workerThread(QThread):
    signal = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()
       self.abort = False

   @pyqtSlot()
   def run(self):
      #print("yeah yeah ")
      time.sleep(0.1)
      app.processEvents()
      self.signal.emit('Done')

   def __del__(self):
      #print("okay okay")
      self.abort = True
      self.wait()


class General(QWidget):

   def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()
      self.initUI()
   def saveClicked(self):
       try:
          tex=[]
          for edit in self.lineedits:
              tex.append(str(edit.text()))
          if tex[0] and tex[1] and tex[2]:
               if ('@gmail.com' in str(tex[1])) or ('@yahoo.com' in str(tex[1])) or ('@' in str(tex[1])):
                  contact=str(tex[2])
                  if self.validContact(contact):
                      self.workerthread = workerThread()
                      self.workerthread.signal.connect(self.savesuccess)
                      self.workerthread.start()
                  else:
                    self.workerthread = workerThread()
                    self.workerthread.signal.connect(self.errorcontactmsg)
                    self.workerthread.start()
               else:
                  self.workerthread = workerThread()
                  self.workerthread.signal.connect(self.erroremailmsg)
                  self.workerthread.start()
        else:
            self.workerthread = workerThread()
            self.workerthread.signal.connect(self.errornormmsg)
            self.workerthread.start()
    except:
        self.workerthread = workerThread()
        self.workerthread.signal.connect(self.crashingmsg)
        self.workerthread.start()
```

Refer this Link for full code to have an Idea - [Link](https://github.com/Rahul14singh/Managemet_sys_PyQt5_openpyxl/blob/master/Management_sys.py)

or even if you just want to initialize then,

```
 class Tetrominoe(object):
    NoShape = 0
 class Shape(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.coords = [[0,0] for i in range(4)]
        self.pieceShape = Tetrominoe.NoShape
        self.setShape(Tetrominoe.NoShape)
```

But using self to call def attributes of one class in another is a better option attach that attribute on main thread by "self. " and access it in any class then.

Quite New with Python but hope this helps.

Go through this - [How would I access variables from one class to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19993795/how-would-i-access-variables-from-one-class-to-another) it will be more helpfull.