# Is it possible to import only a selected variable

Tags: python, variables, import

I'm new here and in python.

I try to import only a single variable or some of them from another file.
I try `from conf import SINGLE_VARIABLE` but it gives me a 
`ImportError: cannot import name 'SINGLE_VARIABLE`

Maybe it is not a good idea in the python *way of coding*, but I'm curious
 if it is possible

Thx

Comment: Yes it is possible. The error message says it cannot find `SINGLE_VARIABLE` in `conf`

Comment: `from conf import SINGLE_VARIABLE` is a good coding style and it will work as long as something named `SINGLE_VARIABLE` is actually in `conf`.

Comment: You can study the module content with `print(dir(module))` or `print(help(module))` .

Comment: Make sure SINGLE_VARIABLE is declared outside a function.

Comment: can you provide your code ?

Comment: see if this answer help you [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19993795/how-would-i-access-variables-from-one-class-to-another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19993795/how-would-i-access-variables-from-one-class-to-another)

Comment: Thx for suggesting @KushalParikh but it's not the same case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, thanks for answering people.

I just ommit to say that I want to import my variable from a *Class*… and in this case, import must be **inside** the appropriate method.

For memory, see my (working) code:

**file1.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from file2 import Message

WORD_LIST = ["hello","bonjour","ola"]

Message(1)
```

**file2.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class Message:

    def __init__(self, index):
        from file1 import WORD_LIST
        self._phrase = WORD_LIST[index] + " world"

    def __str__(self):
        return self._phrase
```

Answer (score 4):

just make sure your varialbe is global for use

**hello1.py**

```
fname = "hello"
lname = "world"
```

**hello2.py**

```
from hello1 import fname
print(fname)
```

**output**

```
hello
```

works with python 3.x