# When returning a function I am getting TypeError: invalid file

Tags: python, class, tkinter, return

I am trying to use a variable in one class in another. I am doing this by returning a function then accessing it in the other class.

My program is trying to display a csv file in a gui using python tkinter.

But all I am getting is this:

> TypeError: invalid file:<< function NewSession.returnCsvFileDir at
>   0x0363E228 >>
>
> File "\cur-fsm\2011$\userdata\11azama\COMPUTER SCIENCE
>   PROJECT\Project (NEW VERSIONS) (1)\NEW PROJECT V7\MainApplication.py",
>   line 188, in showCSV with open(testCSV, newline = "") as file: 
>   TypeError: invalid file: << function NewSession.returnCsvFileDir at
>   0x0363E228 >>

This is some of my code:

From the first class:

```
def returnCsvFileDir(self, master, csvFileDir):
    NewSession.csvFile = print(csvFileDir)
    return NewSession.csvFile
```

From the other class:

```
def showCSV(self,master,NewSession):
    testCSV = (NewSession.returnCsvFileDir)
    print(testCSV)
    with open(testCSV, newline = "") as file:
       reader = csv.reader(file)
       r = 0
       for col in reader:
          c = 0
          for row in col:
             label = Label(root, width = 10, height = 2, \
                                   text = row, relief = RIDGE)
             label.grid(row = r, column = c)
             c += 1
          r += 1
```

Comment: Apparently, `testCSV` isn't what you think it is. It looks like a function, not a filename, just as the error is telling you.

Comment: This line `NewSession.csvFile = print(csvFileDir)` looks suspicious to me. `NewSession.csvFile` should be `None` if you set it to the result of `print()`.

Comment: @bryanoakley - what do you mean? I am returning a **file directory** from 'returnCsvFileDir', not a function.

Comment: No, you're returning `None` from `returnCsvFileDir`. And even if you are returning a directory, you can't open a directory as if it were a csv file.

Comment: Everything works when i replace testCSV in 'with open(testCSV ' with a file directory of a csv file

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Comments to some of the answers imply that there's more going on than you are telling us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem is that NewSession.csvFile = print(csvFileDir) is assigning NewSession.csvFile to the return value of print(csvFile), which is None.  You are not assigning a function to NewSession.csvfile.

To fix, you might consider just using

`NewSession.csvFile = print`

Also, you are calling `print(testcsv)`m which will not work, since `testcsv` does not return a value.  You probably want to *call* testcsv with an argument.

At a higher level, it looks like you're trying to use a closure and partially evaluated function to grab the `csvFileDir` parameter and pass it inside a function call.  While you could do this, (I haven't done this in python, so I don't know the details), I'd recommend finding a simpler way to just pass the filename around as a string and not worry about passing a function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem starts in these two lines:

```
testCSV = (NewSession.returnCsvFileDir)
...
with open(testCSV, newline = "") as file:
```

First, you are setting `testCSV` to a function, rather than the *result* of the function. Second, you are passing this *function* to `open`, but `open` expects a path to a file.

My guess is that you are intending to *call* `NewSession.returnCsvFileDir`, so the first step would be to do that, and assign the result to `testCSV`:

```
testCSV = NewSession.returnCsvFileDir(...)
```

However, that function takes two arguments, but I don't know what those arguments are supposed to be, so you'll have to figure that out.

This brings up the second problem, which is that `NewSession.returnCsvFileDir(...)` returns `None`, even when called with proper arguments.  That is because of these two lines:

```
NewSession.csvFile = print(csvFileDir)
return NewSession.csvFile
```

This sets `NewSession.csvFile` to the result of `print`, and `print` returns `None`.

I don't know what the solution is because it *seems* that the function is supposed to return the path to a file, but all it is given is a directory and something called `master`. I don't know how it's supposed to use those two in order to compute a path to a file.

Comment: Asked user to input a file directory in a previous function. I then wanted to use this directory in another class. I looked up how to do this and found a way: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19993795/how-would-i-access-variables-from-one-class-to-another). I then tried to use this idea but it didn't work so I tested if my 'showCSV(self,master,NewSession)' function would work by replacing the 'testCSV' with a file directory and IT WORKED. I believe the problem lies with the 'def returnCsvFileDir(self, master, csvFileDir)'. Ihavefollowedthe answerinlinkexactlybuthadnoluck.

Comment: Do you know how to return a file directory that has been passed in to the function so i can use it in another class

Comment: @AdamAzamYear12: I don't understand the question. To return a directory, just return the directory (eg: `return the_directory`). But why do you need to call a function if you already have the file?

Comment: I am trying to ask the user to input a file directory of a csv file so I can alter it. There will be a before and after of the csv spreadsheet that will be displayed on the screen. I just want to know how I would get a variable from one class to another. Since the users spreadsheet's file directory is stored in a variable in a different class. I was trying to use a function to do this.

Comment: @AdamAzamYear12: that information is fairly useless. You presented some code and asked why it didn't work, and my answer and at least one other answer explains why. We can only go off of what is present in the question.