# How do I resolve AttributeError: Type Object 'StartPage' Has no Attribute 'ICID'? Aka How do I reference variables from another class?

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, mysql-python

How does one reference variables within a frame/class? My friend built the class/frame system and I don't really understand it, but I know if I mess with it anymore than I have already it breaks. I'm trying to insert StartPage.ICID into a table, but it gives me this error 
"AttributeError: type object 'StartPage' has no attribute 'ICID'"

I've tried everything I can think, no matter where I define ICID this goes wrong.

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

    def __init__(self,parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
       #tkinter.Label(self, text= "Insurance Company!!!").grid(pady=10, padx = 10)
    #Value gotcha 
        self.ICID = tk.StringVar()
        self.ICIDEntry = tk.Entry(self, width = 25, textvariable = self.ICID).grid(column = 1, row = 1)

       button3 = ttk.Button(self, text="Export",
                           command=lambda: exportAll()).grid(column=0, row=19)

def data_entry():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('pagesInfo.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    #def table1():
    c.execute("INSERT INTO insuranceInfo (ICID, InsAddress, InsName) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
              (StartPage.ICID.get(), insAddress, insName))
    conn.commit()
```

I've cut a lot of the code to post it here, let me know if there's something else you need to see.

If I uncomment def table1(): I don't get an error but the ICID isn't inserted-I don't think that function is called anywhere.

Thank you so much for any help.

edit:
I came up with an awful work around- export functions for each page.

Comment: You can't access instance variable using class name.  You should access it via instance of the class.  For example, `page = StartPage(...)`, then `page.ICID.get()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how-would-i-access-variables-from-one-class-to-another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19993795), Read up on [Tutorial - 9.3.5. Class and Instance Variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)