# Function works natively but not when called from another page

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a tkinter page that works by calling other tkinter pages, each with their own functions. When I call the page locally, the function works, but when it is called from the other page it doesn't work.
The function used to call the other page is this.

```
from tkinter import *
import subprocess
import tkinter.messagebox
import os.path

class meh:
    def __init__ (self,root):
        self.root =root
        self.root.title("ODIN")
        self.root.geometry("1350x750+0+0")
        self.root.config(bg="ghost white")

        def ap():
            subprocess.call(["python.exe",r"C:\Users\felix\Documents\FelixPython\AttendancePageAdmin.py"])
            #AttendancePage.Attendance(Tk())

        MainFrame = Frame(self.root, bg="Ghost White")
        MainFrame.grid()

        CallButtonFrame = Frame(MainFrame, bd=2, width=1350, height=70, padx=18, pady=10, bg="blue2", relief = RIDGE)
        CallButtonFrame.pack(side=TOP)


        self.btnAttend = Button(CallButtonFrame, text = 'Attendance page' , font=('ariel',20,'bold'),height=1,width=10, bd=4, command = ap)
        self.btnAttend.grid(row=0, column=0)

if __name__=='__main__':
    root = Tk()
    application = meh(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you provide the error message you get? My guess is that `AttendancePageAdmin.py` uses modules that are not in your `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: _”Doesn’t work”_ is too vague. What do you mean? Does it throw an error? Do the wrong thing? Something else?

Comment: The program AttendancePageAdmin is designed to access an SQL database, when I press the button in the windo it gives the error "sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: Attendance"

Comment: Read [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48045508/7414759). Does this answer your question? [how-would-i-access-variables-from-one-class-to-another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19993795)