# Calling from another class in tkinter python 3.6

Tags: python, function, class, tkinter, python-3.6

Please how can I call 'new' in class staff from self.btn2 in class intro
Here is my code

```
import tkinter
class intro:
   def __init__(self, page1):
     self.page1 = page1
     
     self.btn = tkinter.Button(page1, text="next", command=self.me).grid(column=0, row=0)
     self.btn2 = tkinter.Button(page1, text="message", command=staff.new(self)).grid(column=1, row=0)
   def me(self):
     self.page2 = tkinter.Toplevel()
     self.b = admin(self.page2)
     self.page1.withdraw()


class admin:
   def __init__(self, page2):
     self.page2 = page2

     self.btn = tkinter.Button(page2, text="next", command=self.me2).grid(column=0, row=0)

   def me2(self):
     self.page3 = tkinter.Toplevel()
     self.b = staff(self.page3)
     self.page2.withdraw()


class staff:
   def __init__(self, page3):
     self.page3 = page3

   def new(self):
       print("hello everybody")

if __name__ == '__main__':
   window = tkinter.Tk()
   app = intro(window)
   window.mainloop()
```

Please help. I want to be able to call 'new' in class staff from button in class intro. I use python 3.6.

Comment: You need an instance of `staff` to call its new() function.

Comment: Please how? I've tried a lot of methods for the instance but not still working

Comment: `lambda: staff(self.page1).new()`

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thanks. Please post your answer so that I can mark you as 'answered'.

Comment: This question already has answers here:[how-would-i-access-variables-from-one-class-to-another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19993795)

Comment: @ stovfl I think someone else would like to get explicit answer using instance with button calling def function from another class

Answer (score 0):

From the comment of @acw1668, I repost the question in a better way as answered

```
import tkinter
class intro:
   def __init__(self, page1):
     self.page1 = page1
     
     self.btn = tkinter.Button(page1, text="next", command=self.me).grid(column=0, row=0)
     self.btn2 = tkinter.Button(page1, text="message", command=lambda: staff(self.page1).new()).grid(column=1, row=0)
   def me(self):
     self.page2 = tkinter.Toplevel()
     self.b = admin(self.page2)
     self.page1.withdraw()


class admin:
   def __init__(self, page2):
     self.page2 = page2

     self.btn = tkinter.Button(page2, text="next", command=self.me2).grid(column=0, row=0)

   def me2(self):
     self.page3 = tkinter.Toplevel()
     self.b = staff(self.page3)
     self.page2.withdraw()


class staff:
   def __init__(self, page3):
     self.page3 = page3

   def new(self):
       print("hello everybody")

if __name__ == '__main__':
   window = tkinter.Tk()
   app = intro(window)
   window.mainloop()
```