# How to get suit in full name rather than a short name in Python

Tags: python-3.4

I wrote the following code for card game. I don't encounter any error while running the program. However, there is one thing I would like to improve. For the method "getSuit", how could I get the full name of suit like 'Clubs' instead of just a short name like 'c'?

```
class Card: # One object of class Card represents a playing card
rank =['','Ace','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven','Eight','Nine','Ten','Jack','Queen','King']
suit = {'d':'Diamonds', 'c':'Clubs', 'h':'Hearts', 's':'Spades'}
def __init__(self, rank=2, suit=0): # Card constructor, executed every time a new Card object is created
    self.rank = rank
    self.suit = suit

def getRank(self): # Obtain the rank of the card
    return self.rank

def getSuit(self): # Obtain the suit of the card
    return self.suit

def bjValue(self): # Obtain the Blackjack value of a card
    Value = {'Ace':'1', 'Two':'2', 'Three':'3', 'Four':'4', 'Five':'5', 'Six':'6', 'Seven':'7', 'Eight':'8', 'Nine':'9', 'Ten':'10', 'Jack':'10', 'Queen':'10', 'King':'10'}
    return min(self.rank, 10)

def __str__(self): # Generate the name of a card in a string
    return "%s of %s" % (Card.rank[int(self.rank)], Card.suit[self.suit])


c1 = Card(1,'c')
print(c1)
print(c1.getRank())
print(c1.getSuit())
print(c1.bjValue())

# Output as below
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Ace of Clubs
1
c
1
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have, the simplest way would probably be something like this:

```
def getSuit(self): # Obtain the suit of the card
    return Card.suit[self.suit]
```

But, keep in mind that you are mixing instance variables and class variables.  You should check out [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714573/instance-variables-vs-class-variables-in-python) if you don't know what that means.