# Class variables in python

Tags: python, class, variables, static

I (accidentally) wrote the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4

class Account:

    balance = 1000

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        print('Withdrawing')
        if(amount > self.balance):
            print("You cannot withdraw that amount!")
        else:
            self.balance -= amount

    def checkBalance(self):
        if (self.balance == 0):
            print("Your account is empty.")
        else:
            print("You still have ", str(self.balance) + "€ euros in your account!")


def Main():
    account1 = Account()
    account2 = Account()

    account1.withdraw(100)
    account1.withdraw(300)

    account1.checkBalance()
    account2.checkBalance()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

output:

```
Withdrawing
Withdrawing
You still have 600€ euros in your account!
You still have 1000€ euros in your account!
```

My questions:

1) why the `balance` variable does not behave as a class (static) variable although it has been declared as such?

2) even if the usage of the `self` keyword when accessing the `balance` variable from within the methods is preventing the static behavior, at which point is an instance copy of the class variable `balance` made? (at least that is what I am inferring, that each object gets its own copy of the -what is supposed to be a class variable- `balance`)

3) by trial and error, I discovered that a way to get the (expected?) behavior is to annotate the methods with @classmethod. Is this s.th like in Java that prevents access of static variables from non-static methods?

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714573/instance-variables-vs-class-variables-in-python) posts but IMHO they do not address the above implications.

Answer (score 4):

The trick is here:

```
self.balance -= amount
```

This actually translates to:

```
self.balance = self.balance - amount
```

Now, the complicated thing is that `self.balance` is not actually the same thing on either side of that assignment. The RHS is evaluated first:  Python tries to find an instance variable, fails, and falls back to the class variable. But now it does the LHS, and here it simply does what it normally does: assigns directly to an instance variable called `balance`.

The point is that the LHS is unaware that the original value came from a class variable; it simply assigns where it is told, to `self.balance`, which is an instance var.

Of course from then on, the instance var exists, so any further reads of `self.balance` will get that rather than the original class variable: the class variable exists unchanged, but is *shadowed* by the instance variable.

When you define the method as a classmethod, the first parameter is no longer the instance (self) but the class itself; for this reason it is customary to call that argument `cls`. So you read and write directly to the class variable.

Comment: Exactly what I would have said, if I could have expressed it so elegantly. If `self.balance` were replaced with `Account.balance` then it would behave as the OP expected.

Comment: perhaps mention that the class variable still exists, it's just that it's not being refered to in the `self.checkBalance` method.

Comment: So when python fails to find an instance variable `self.x`, it falls back to looking up for a class variable `x` ? In that case that actually takes place in the comparison `if amount > self.balance`. which precedes the statement with the decrement operator.  Also: is the `@classmethod` annotation preventing the creation of instance variable DESPITE the existence of the `self.`  ?  Is the annotation instructing the interpreter to ignore anything before (including) the `.` ?

Comment: Well, it does it everywhere, but the interesting stuff is what I describe happening in the assignment statement. And no, the point is that what you're calling `self` in the classmethod is not really self but cls: it's the class, not an instance. Don't forget `self` and `cls` are just conventions, you can use whatever names you like, but it's best to be clear that in the case of a classmethod the first param is the class object.