# What is wrong with the following code in Python?

Tags: python, class, static

Below is the documented way to create a mutable non-static class variable in python.

```
class Cla:

    def __init__(self):
        self.arr = []


    def showIds(self):
        print(str(id(self.arr)))


    def show(self):
        print(self.arr)


a = Cla()
b = Cla()
a.showIds()
b.showIds()

a.arr.append(10)
b.arr.append(20)
a.show()
b.show()
```

And it works (Sample output ...)

```
140174126200712
140174126185032
[10]
[20]
```

However, to accept some arguments while creating, I modified the `__init__` to below. (Only change is in the `__init__` function.

```
class Cla:

    def __init__(self, arr=[]):
        self.arr = arr


    def showIds(self):
        print(str(id(self.arr)))


    def show(self):
        print(self.arr)


a = Cla()
b = Cla()
a.showIds()
b.showIds()

a.arr.append(10)
b.arr.append(20)
a.show()
b.show()
```

And suddenly the list becomes shared.

```
140711339502152
140711339502152
[10, 20]
[10, 20]
```

My question is why? What is wrong with above approach.

PS: I have gone through below already.

[Static class variables in Python -- Lists & Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30809431/static-class-variables-in-python-lists-objects)

[How to avoid having class data shared among instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680528/how-to-avoid-having-class-data-shared-among-instances)

Comment: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments

Comment: "Below is the documented way to create a mutable non-static class variable in python." => in Python, this is called an "instance attribute" (by opposition with "class attributes" which belong to the class object itself and are shared between instances).

Comment: Accurate pointer @Goyo, Thank you