# Why can't django set attributes outside the database?

Tags: python, django

It seems like django was designed to store data in databases. While writing my first app, I forgot about this and tried to set up a model like so:

```
class Team(models.Model): 
    stage = 0
    users_score = {}
```

I soon realised that I could get this attribute but I couldn't set it:

```
team = Team()
team.stage = 1
team.save()
print Team.objects.get(pk=1).stage
```

This would print 0 when I expected 1. In my models file I change `stage = 0` to

```
stage = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

And it works as I want it to. Why can django get this attribute, but not set it? I'm guessing it's because the setattr() method has been changed. How can I verify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do the assignment `team.stage = 1` it only changes the `stage` value of the  instance that the variable `team` is pointing to. Since it is not a model field, it won't be stored in the database when you call `.save()` method and, it won't be persisted through multiple `Team` instances.

Because of that, newly created teams won't have any idea about the current value of `stage`:

```
>>> t1 = Team()
>>> t1.stage = 1

>>> t2 = Team()
>>> print t2.stage
0
```

Also, it is a class variable, which means you can assign its value on class level, so that all instances created from it will be able to access the same value:

```
>>> Team.stage = 1

>>> t1 = Team()
>>> print t1.stage
1
>>> t2 = Team()
>>> print t2.stage
1
```

Since `Team.objects.get(pk=1)` will always return a new instance every time it was called, holding a class variable won't help you much, you have to use a model field, preferably `models.IntegerField`, in order for all instances to have the same value for `stage`.

Comment: So in summary, `team.save()` doesn't work on the `.stage` attribute because it's not linked to the database. But I can still get this attribute because `team = Team()` will assign `team.stage` from my models.py file?

Comment: Exactly. `stage` will be set to `0` by default for every instance once you created them but `.save()` only persists attributes defined as model fields. By the way, it is a class variable however, I think you probably should define it as an [instance variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714573/instance-variables-vs-class-variables-in-python) instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
stage = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Here `stage` is a database field with `int` type and `default` constraint set to `0`. Django knows, how to manage this field.

```
stage = 0
```

Here `stage` is a class field. Django does not know, how to manage it in the database layer. That is why Django skips this field.

> Why can django get this attribute, but not set it?

Django is only a framework. Python manages all classes, objects and others. When it creates an object of your class, it initializes the field to zero.