# Create 3 instances of a class and store different values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a program which will create 3 instances of a class and store different values for different people.

The current code that I have will output the last person's information. I do not know if I correctly set up a class or not but any help is much needed.

```
#Main module
def main():
    #Declare variables
    name = ""
    address = ""
    age = ""
    phoneNumber = ""
    person1Information = personalInformation(name, address, age, phoneNumber)
    person2Information = personalInformation(name, address, age, phoneNumber)
    person3Information = personalInformation(name, address, age, phoneNumber)

    #Person 1
    name, address, age, phoneNumber = getPersonInformation(name, address, age, phoneNumber)
    storePerson1Information(person1Information, name, address, age, phoneNumber)
    #Person 2
    name, address, age, phoneNumber = getPersonInformation(name, address, age, phoneNumber)
    storePerson2Information(person2Information, name, address, age, phoneNumber)
    #Person 3
    name, address, age, phoneNumber = getPersonInformation(name, address, age, phoneNumber)
    storePerson3Information(person3Information, name, address, age, phoneNumber)

    #Display
    displayInformation(person1Information, person2Information, person3Information)

#Ask for information
def getPersonInformation(name, address, age, phoneNumber):
    name = str(input("What is this person's name?"))
    address = str(input("What is the address for this person?"))
    age = int(input("What is this person's age?"))
    phoneNumber = str(input("What is their phone number?"))
    return name, address, age, phoneNumber

#Add peron 1's information to class
def storePerson1Information(person1Information, name, address, age, phoneNumber):
    person1Information.setName(name)
    person1Information.setAddress(address)
    person1Information.setAge(age)
    person1Information.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
    return

#add peron 2's information to class
def storePerson2Information(person2Information, name, address, age, phoneNumber):
    person2Information.setName(name)
    person2Information.setAddress(address)
    person2Information.setAge(age)
    person2Information.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
    return

#Add person 3's information to class
def storePerson3Information(person3Information, name, address, age, phoneNumber):
    person3Information.nameInformation = name
    person3Information.addressInformation = address
    person3Information.ageInformation = age
    person3Information.phoneNumberInformation = phoneNumber
    return

#Display the results
def displayInformation(person1Information, person2Information, person3Information):
    print("Person 1's name:", person1Information.getName())
    print("Person 2's name:", person2Information.getName())
    print("Person 3's name:", person3Information.getName())
    print("Person 1's age:", person1Information.getAge())
    print("Person 2's age:", person2Information.getAge())
    print("Person 3's age:", person3Information.getAge())
    print("Person 1's address:", person1Information.getAddress())
    print("Person 2's address:", person2Information.getAddress())
    print("Person 3's address:", person3Information.getAddress())
    print("Person 1's phone number:", person1Information.getPhoneNumber())
    print("Person 2's phone number:", person2Information.getPhoneNumber())
    print("Person 3's phone number:", person3Information.getPhoneNumber())

#Class holding variables and methods
class personalInformation(object):
    #Declare vaibales
    nameInformation = ""
    addressInformation = ""
    ageInformation = 0
    phoneNumberInformation = ""
    #Initialize?
    def __init__(self, nameInformation, addressInformation, ageInformation, phoneNumberInformation):
        self.nameInformation = nameInformation
        self.addressInformation = addressInformation
        self.ageInformation = ageInformation
        self.phoneNumberInformation = phoneNumberInformation
    #Modifiers
    def setName(self, name):
        nameInformation = name
        return
    def setAddress(self, address):
        addressInformation = address
        return
    def setAge(self, age):
        ageInformation = age
        return
    #Accessor
    def setPhoneNumber(self, phoneNumber):
        phoneNumberInformation = phoneNumber
    def getName(self):
        return self.nameInformation
    def getAge(self):
        return self.ageInformation
    def getAddress(self):
        return self.addressInformation
    def getPhoneNumber(self):
        return self.phoneNumberInformation

#Call main module
main()
```

Comment: You should read up on [class vs instance variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714573/instance-variables-vs-class-variables-in-python). You are creating variables that belong to *all members of your class* instead of *each member*

Comment: Also you should [avoid setters and getters in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627002/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-use-getters-and-setters)

Comment: And you should learn how to use the same set of functions three times (for the three persons), not three near-identical copies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I think you're right. I don't know if my answer is what you're looking for, but I believe that all you have to do is something like this:

Code:

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def setName(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def getName(self):
        return self.name

def main():

    person1 = Person("John")
    person2 = Person("Fred")
    person3 = Person("Paul")

    print person1.name
    print person2.name
    print person3.name

main()
```

It's really simple and it works. If you need it, you can introduce more fields in the defintion of Person **init**. Is this what you were asking for?

Comment: Yes thank you. I found that when I declared the person1Information variable after the getPersonInformation() function was called, everything displayed correctly.