# Trying to pass list of variable in class and function in object oriented manner

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'm trying to pass variable list in Class and Function in object oriented manner but facing some error, I don't understand what wrong with it and I'm using PyDev in Eclipse

## CODE

```
class Mydetails:
    __details = ''

    def __init__(self,details):     # constructor
        #self.__details['country'] = details['country']
        self.__details = details

    def set_element(self,details):
        self.__details = details
    
    def get_list(self,details):
        return self.__details
 
details = ['ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL']
pdetails = Mydetails()
pdetails.set_element(details)
print(pdetails.get_list())
```

## OUTPUT

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\workspace\python\pythonapp\list.py", line 18, in <module>
    pdetails = Mydetails()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'details'
```

Comment: Please correct the formatting here. Python is highly dependent on indentation.

Comment: As an aside, this: `__details = ''` is almost not doing what you think it is. This creates a *class-level variable*, instead of an instance variable. You then *shadow this variable* on each instance in `__init__`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga exactly I'm shadowing variable values in self so that I can get it from get function.

Comment: @VrushalRaut What? No, you are shadowing a totally useless **class-level variable** that you create when you assign in the class block.  You should just use `self.details`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714573/instance-variables-vs-class-variables-in-python)  about class-level variables vs instance variables. Furthermore, you are then using double-underscore name-mangling mixed with getters and setters, not really the way things are done in Python. See [this questions for more about that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7456865/5014455)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  I understand what you saying but it just prototype so I'm making base model in OOP so that later on I can do my project code on that basis , right now I'm passing variable of array(list) may be in future it will multiple variables so thats why getter and setter use so that "self" variable sound efficient when get function is call.

Comment: @VrushalRaut I'm sorry, I am not following you.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for help checkout code I fixed, now it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my code ,It was error in function `def get_list(self,details):` changed to `def get_details(self):` because details parameter already copied in self so it not allow the same thats why throwing error, but below code is fixed and work fine with function calling and defined object also correct from previous code.

## CODE

```
class Mydetails:
    __details = ''     #protected


    def __init__(self,details={}):  # constructor
        self.__details = details


    def set_details(self,details):        # function
        self.__details = details

    def get_details(self):
        return self.__details

    def toString(self):
        return 'Welcome {}'.format(self.__details)


new_details = ['xyz','klm','nop']
pdetails = Mydetails()
pdetails.set_details(new_details)
print(pdetails.get_details())
```

## OUTPUT

```
['xyz', 'klm', 'nop']
```

Answer (score 6):

in this line:

```
def __init__(self,details):
```

you made the init function take a parameter (**details**), but here:

```
pdetails = Mydetails()
```

you arent giving it a parameter! what you probably wanted to do there is:

```
pdetails = Mydetails(details)
```

on a side note your `def get_list(self,details):` function doesn't make sense, why are you passing it a parameter that doesn't get used?

Comment: I'm passing parameters to constructor and function so first set the variable values and then get output from other function.

Comment: but you DIDN'T pass the parameter. you declared it, but then didn't actually pass it

Comment: I tried your method  but still getting same error, so how to do that ?

Comment: you cant get the same error if you tried what i suggested

Comment: I want to make __details = '' protected thats why it is outside of __init__(self,details)

Comment: @VrushalRaut That isn't what you are doing. This creates a class-level variable, instead of an instance variable. You then shadow this variable on each instance in `__init__`. What do you even mean by "protected"? Python does not have access modifiers