# Python - Confused about inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x

I write the test code with 3 classes , and using Chain of Responsibility design pattern , the code below

and I print `print(c._abc is b._abc)`, the answer is True , but my original think is that the two are different.

Then , Round 2 , I uncomment `self._abc = kwargs` and comment other 3 lines , 
the answer become False .

Why is it so?

```
import abc

class A:
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    _abc = {}

    def __init__(self,successor=None,**kwargs):
        self._successor = successor

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def handlerRequest(self):
        pass

class B(A):

    def __init__(self,successor=None,**kwargs):
        self._successor = successor
        print(kwargs)
        # self._abc = kwargs                 # round 2<---uncomment here
        self._abc['a'] = kwargs['a']         # round 2<---comment here
        self._abc['b'] = kwargs['b']         # round 2<---comment here
        self._abc['Hello'] = 'World'         # round 2<---comment here

    def handlerRequest(self):
        if (self._successor is not None):
            self._successor.handlerRequest()

        print(self._abc)

class C(A):

    def handlerRequest(self):
        if (self._successor is not None):
            self._successor.handlerRequest()
        print(self._abc)

list = {'a':1,'b':2}
b = B(**list)
c = C(b)
print(c._abc is b._abc)
c.handlerRequest()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First just to make it clear I would like to state that `_abc` is a class variable, not an instance variable so its address space is shared across parent and child class. Any change in the **original** `_abc` object affects all the class's `_abc` object. Read about class and instance variable ([here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714573/instance-variables-vs-class-variables-in-python) and [here at DO](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-and-instance-variables-in-python-3))

To check that `_abc` share the same address space we can use python built-in [id()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id):

> id() Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer (or long
>   integer) which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object
>   during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may
>   have the same id() value.

To check this in the first round we can do:

```
In [33]: id(c._abc)
Out[33]: 4454841440 

In [34]: id(b._abc)
Out[34]: 4454841440

In [36]: id(A._abc)
Out[36]: 4454841440

In [38]: id(B._abc)
Out[38]: 4454841440

In [39]: id(C._abc)
Out[39]: 4454841440
```

All of them gives the same value for id(). In round 2, when you uncomment `self._abc = kwargs` see what happens to the value of id():

```
In [8]: id(b._abc)
Out[8]: 4585625712 # its different from A._abc and c._abc why?

In [9]: id(c._abc)
Out[9]: 4585627152 # same as A._abc

In [10]: id(A._abc)
Out[10]: 4585627152 # this is same as c._abc
```

Value of b._abc gets changed but the value of c._abc and A._abc remains the same. So, what is actually happening here?

When in round 1 you do:

```
# self._abc = kwargs                 
self._abc['a'] = kwargs['a']
self._abc['b'] = kwargs['b']
self._abc['Hello'] = 'World'
```

You are actually modifying the shared class variable `_abc`. Your code here is not creating a new `self._abc` object it is modifying the original `self._abc` class variable object but in round 2 when you do:

```
self._abc = kwargs
```

Here, the code is assigning `kwargs`, **which is a dictionary with its own address space**, to `self._abc`. `self._abc` becomes class B's instance variable and it is only available to the class B's objects.

To verify this point you can modify your class B to print id's as:

```
In [11]: class B(A):
    ...:
    ...:     def __init__(self,successor=None,**kwargs):
    ...:         self._successor = successor
    ...:         print(id(self._abc))
    ...:         print(id(kwargs))
    ...:         self._abc = kwargs
    ...:         print(id(self._abc))

In [12]: b = B(**list)
4585627152 # original self._abc id
4583538904 # kwargs object's id
4583538904 # New self._abc id
```

As you can see originally self._abc had address `4585627152` and kwargs had `4583538904` but after `self._abc= kwargs` `self._abc`'s new id is 4583538904.

Comment: Thank you for your reply , I found that if I create B or C instances in same py file , they share same _abc , is that python mechanism ?

Comment: and if I want to shared object like dict , is this a good pattern ,  or maybe occur some problem ?

Comment: @RelaxZeroC Glad that it helped. No, actually when you do `class A:  _abc = {}` you are creating a class variable and when you do `self.abc = {}` you are creating class instance variable: In case of class variable classes share same _abc variable and in the case of instance variable classes create their own _abc varibale. I will edit tha answer.

Comment: @RelaxZeroC Generally speaking, if _abc is a constant that you want to share across class and do not modify it it's a good pattern but if you are modifying it in your classes it's better to create instance variables as you might not know which class modified it.

Comment: you mean B,C has it own _abc ? I will modify _abc and I just hope only have one _abc in there , but if B,C create it's own _abc , then _abc  will different . Or I should create other class(ex.SaveABC) to save _abc and let B,C to get _abc from SaveABC ?

Comment: @RelaxZeroC do you want _abc to be shared across the instances of A,B and C class objects in such a way that changing _abc will affect it for all three class objects?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160372/discussion-between-relax-zeroc-and-amit-tripathi).