# Can a particular instance of a class make its own variables in python?

Tags: python

Can a particular instance make its own variable in python, if yes would it be available to other instances of the class?

for eg:

```
class A():
    Var1 = 10

inst1 = A()

inst1.Var1 # will be 10
```

but can inst1 make it's own variables like Var2 etc and will these Variables be available to other class A instances like inst2?

In other Words, is a variable, which is bound to an instance of a class, accessible to another instance of the same class?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to do? This is a little confusing

Comment: A class can have "static" class variables that are shared between all instances - one changes it, all get the change.

Comment: what's an "own variable"? why wouldn't it be able to?  available to other instances how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instance variables vs. class variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714573/instance-variables-vs-class-variables-in-python)

Comment: What exactly is meant by "make its own variable in python"? Do you mean can a class create variables with values specific to each instances?

Comment: @Christian Dean He specifically asked to add a new attribute name (e.g. Var2)

Comment: Do you want instances to create their own new variables dynamically or are you just asking about adding variables to an instance later?

Comment: No he didn't @BrianM.Sheldon - not at first that is. [His _originally_ question said](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50554821/1) _"Can a particular instance make its own variable in python, if yes would it be available to other instances of the class?"_ Yes, the OP has edited his question now to clarify what he wants, but at the time it was not clear what he was asking for, and my comment was inquiring about his original post.

Comment: An instance making its own variable is dynamic creation.  The attribute name was a clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the most common use case is for instances to have their "own" variables ("data attributes" in Python terminology) which are not shared between instances. The variables `x` and `y` below are examples of such "own" variables (every instance of class `A` gets its own variable `x` when the constructor is called, and `inst1` also gets its own variable `y` later):

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):     # Constructor - called when A is instantiated
        self.x = 10         # Creates x for self only (i.e. for each instance in turn)

inst1 = A()
inst1.x = 15                # Changes x for inst1 only
inst1.y = 20                # Creates y for inst1 only
print(inst1.x, inst1.y)     # 15 20

inst2 = A()
print(inst2.x)              # 10
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for clearing my doubt. How is this concept different in java and other languages then?

Comment: No conceptual difference. Instance variables (what you call "own" variables) are an important feature of object oriented programming. By the way, if your original question has been answered to your satisfaction, you should accept the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

To dynamically add attributes to a class or instance you can use `setattr`:

```
class MyClass(object):
    pass

my_instance = MyClass()


# add attribute to class
setattr(MyClass, 'new_attribute', 'added')

# Class now has attribute
print(MyClass.new_attribute == 'added')  # True

# Which is also available to instance
print(my_instance.new_attribute == 'added')  # True

# Add attribute to instance
setattr(my_instance, 'instance_only', 'yup')

# Instance now has attribute
print(my_instance.instance_only == 'yup')  # True

# Class does not have attribute
MyClass.instance_only # Raises AttributeError

# Add attribute to instances class
settatr(type(my_instance), 'instance_only', 'not anymore')

# Now the attribute is available to the class as well
print(MyClass.instance_only == 'not anymore')  # True

# New instances will also have the attributes
new_instance = MyClass()
print(new_instance.new_attribute == 'added')  # True
```

If you are not adding them dynamically see @gilch's answer

Comment: There is no reason to use `setattr` here; nothing is dynamic.

Comment: An instance making its own variable is the definition of dynamic

Comment: @DanielRoseman How would you propose adding a new variable without being dynamic

Comment: `setattr` is only required if the attr name is unknown until runtime. E.g. a function that sets an attr typed in by the user. But they can still be set dynamically (i.e. at runtime) using the dot syntax if the name is known statically, e.g. a function that always assigns to the same name, but the user types in which object to use it on.

Comment: @gilch it all depends on what the OP's intention is, which is unclear from the question.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you set the variable in the class's dict or the instance's dict.

```
>>> class A:
    var = 10


>>> inst1 = A()
>>> inst2 = A()
>>> inst1.var  # not in instance, so looked up in class
10
>>> inst2.var
10
>>> inst2.var = 20  # instance attr shadows that from class
>>> inst2.var
20
>>> A.var = 30  # class attr can also be altered
>>> inst1.var
30
>>> inst2.var
20
>>> del inst2.var  # deleting instance attr reveals shadowed class attr
>>> inst2.var
30
>>> inst1.var2 = 'spam'
>>> inst2.var2  # new attr was set on inst1, so not available in inst2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#663>", line 1, in <module>
    inst2.var2
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'var2'
>>> inst1.__class__.var3 = 'eggs'  # same as A.var3 = 'eggs'
>>> inst2.var3  # new attr was set on the class, so all instances see it.
'eggs'
```

Comment: The OP is asking about adding additional attributes not availability of already defined attributes

Comment: The initial question was the same, just the later edits made it more clear

Comment: @BrianM.Sheldon new attrs follow the same rules. Added more examples to make that clear.

Comment: The OP asked if the instance could make its own variables, which implies dynamically.  If dynamic attributes are not required, your example is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the actual use may be questionable, you actually can bind new attributes to a class definition in a way that they are available to all instances of that class:

```
class A(object):
    attrib_one = 'VALUE'

    def add_class_attrib(self, name, value):
        # Bind new attribute to class definition, **not** to self
        setattr(A, name, value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Instantiate _before_ changing A's class attributes
    a = A()
    b = A()
    # Add a new class attribute using only _one_ instance
    a.add_class_attrib('attrib_two', 'OTHER')
    # Print attributes of both instances
    print([e for e in dir(a) if not e.startswith('__')])
    print([e for e in dir(b) if not e.startswith('__')])

    # Create new instance _after_ changing A's class attribs
    c = A()
    # Print attributes of new instance
    print([e for e in dir(c) if not e.startswith('__')])
```

Running this code will print the following:

```
['add_class_attrib', 'attrib_one', 'attrib_two']
['add_class_attrib', 'attrib_one', 'attrib_two']
['add_class_attrib', 'attrib_one', 'attrib_two']
```

And you see, that -- even if a *class* attribute is added to the class definition *after* an instance of it has been created, the newly created class attribute in fact is available to all other instances of that (changed) class.