# Method name is not defined error even if it is defined above in python

Tags: python, class, methods

I have defined one method and I tried to call it inside a constructor, However I am getting error "userDetailsValidation" is not defined, Even If I have defined it above the constructor. Here is my code:

```
class PythonAssignment:
    FirstName = ""
    LastName = ""
    dateOfBirth = ""

    def userDetailsValidation(fieldvalue, fieldName, database):
        for entry in database:
            if fieldName in entry and entry[fieldName] == fieldvalue:
                return True

    def printRequiredUserInfo(FirstName, fieldname, AccountNumber, Accountbalance, Database):
        for entry in Database:
            if fieldname in entry and entry[fieldname] == FirstName:
                print(entry)

    def __init__(self):
        self.FirstName = str(input("Enter First Name").upper())
        while True:
            if (userDetailsValidation(FirstName, "FirstName", newSortedDatabase)) == True:
                userDetails.append(FirstName)
                break
            else:
                print(" First Name did not matched with the database")
                FirstName = str(input("Enter First Name").upper())


userObject = PythonAssignment()
```

Comment: There is no need to use a class at all here. Do you have a specific reason to use one?

Comment: Just to practice OOP concept.

Comment: Besides what I wrote below, you also should read about [class vs instance variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714573/instance-variables-vs-class-variables-in-python) as you are misusing those as well.

Comment: Ok thanks for the solution.

Comment: @RohnKerry if the point is to learn OO, then do it the right way... A class is not a replacement for a module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should label your methods that don't use `self` as static

```
@staticmethod
def userDetailsValidation(fieldvalue, fieldName, database):
```

and

```
@staticmethod
def printRequiredUserInfo(FirstName,fieldname,AccountNumber,Accountbalance,Database):
```

then to call them, you use the class scope

```
if PythonAssignment.userDetailsValidation(FirstName, "FirstName", newSortedDatabase):
```

If your method do need the state of the object, then you should call them from `self`

```
self.SomeMethod(args, etc)
```

Comment: Does this resolved the problem at your end, I am stuck at FirstName. FirstName is not defined. Can you help me with this?

Comment: No as I mentioned you have other problems as well. Your `FirstName`, etc should not be up at the class level, they should be defined in `__init__` only and be an attribute of `self`, e.g. `self.FirstName`. Then any of your class methods that aren't static should take `self` as the first argument, then they can access any member variables