# Python: How to Create a Class Based on certain criteria

Tags: python

Here is the Problem Statement.

The Scenario is that I have many Platforms, and each of the platform has certain unique identities, lets consider it as graphic_cards, hardware, software and interfaces.

1. Each of the Platforms can run a specific set of commands that is compatible with the given platform.
2. Example:

   - **Platform 1**: Zodiac: GC1, HW1, SW1, INT1
   - ....
   - **Platform n**: Star: GCn, HWn, SWn, int n

I need to write a code in such a way that the script analyses which platform it is and runs the commands specific to only that Platform.

So far I have tried this,

```
class Platform(object):
a = None
B = None
C = None
D = None

def __init__(self, A,B, C, D):
    self.A = A
    self.B = B
    self.C = C
    self.D = D

class ZODIAC(Platform):

A = attr.A_map_dict

def __init__(self, A, B, C, D):
    super(ZODIAC, self).__init__(A, B, C, D)
```

Comment: Please be more specific, at this point, your question is rather hard to understand.

Comment: Don't create class variables `a = None`, `B = None`, etc., `self.A` will create an instance variable, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714573/instance-variables-vs-class-variables-in-python

Answer (score 0):

I would make a set of subclasses, and then a *completely separate method* to analyze your parameters and generate the class you want:

```
class Platform(object):
    a = None
    b = None
    ...
    def __init__(self, A, B, C, D):
        ...
    ...
    def execute_commands():
         # abstract method - platform-specific, defined by subclasses

class ZODIAC(Platform):
    A = attr.A_map_dict
    ...
    @override
    def execute_commands():
        # platform-specific behavior, overriding superclass

def generate_platform(a, b, c, d):
    if a == 'onething' and b == 'anotherthing':
        return ZODIAC(a, b, c, d)
    elif c == 'somethingelse':
        return OTHER_PLATFORM(a, b, c, d)
    ...
```

Write `generate_platform()` in such a way that it determines which platform is correct from the variables given. It will then return an instance of the appropriate subclass of `Platform`. This is an illustration of the principle of *polymorphism*, one of the pillars of object-oriented programming.