# list inside class being appended when other object is active

Tags: python

I'm creating a school project that needs to record the events of each iteration of a subroutine in a list. However, it appends both players list. How do I stop this from happening?

For example:

```
class Player:

    l = list()
    def append_list(self,i):
        self.l.append(i)

p1 = Player()
p2 = Player()

for i in range(0,5):

    p1.append_list(i)
    print(p1.l)
    p2.append_list(i)
    print(p1.l)
```

This code outputs:

```
[0]
[0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

but I need it to output:

```
[0]
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use separate *instance variables* instead of shared *class variables* - that way each of your player instances has its *own* list instead of a shared one:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.l = []       # create a instance list l

    def append_list(self,i):
        self.l.append(i)

# other code identical
```

Output:

```
[0]
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

More:

- [Instance variables vs. class variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714573/instance-variables-vs-class-variables-in-python)
- [PyTut: Class and Instance Variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)