# Real word simulation of a Printer using Queue in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, instance-variables

I am going through the book "Problem Solving with Algorithms and Data Structures using Python"

In the chapter for Queues there is a printer simulation with the Printer class.

here is the definition of Printer class:

```
class Printer():
def __init__(self, ppm):
    self.pagerate = ppm
    self.currentTask = None
    self.timeRemaining = 0
```

My question is that how are the instance variable not present in parameter but still defined (e.g. currentTask and timeRemaining)?

Is it a practice in Python and is there any other better way to do this?

Comment: http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/BasicDS/SimulationPrintingTasks.html

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects

> The instantiation operation (“calling” a class object) creates an
>   empty object. Many classes like to create objects with instances
>   customized to a specific initial state. Therefore a class may define a
>   special method named `__init__()`, like this:
>
> ```
> def __init__(self):
>     self.data = []
> ```

Also [Instance variables vs. class variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714573/instance-variables-vs-class-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass values for all parameters. By writing `self.variable_name` we automatically create instance variables. They don't need to be initiated with passed values. You can initiate them with `None` values.

Comment: well none of the documents provided here answer my question.But I guess i can take away from this question that i can create variable w/o passing values.Maybe I did not frame the question right.