# Is there a way to set a global variable within a method of a class but is unique to every object of the class?

Tags: python, class, object, global-variables

Within my class of `categories`, I have several functions that reference to a variable. For them to access the variable I had to make the variable *global*. It worked, it's fine, when there only is one object within the class. When it had two, the results blew. Other objects also had access to the *global variable* and changed its value. Is there a way I could set-up a global variable for the class methods but are unique to every class instances?

**EDIT:**

Thanks guys, I am now enlightened with using the `__init__` method. There was no need to use *global variables*.

Comment: I don't understand: you want to make a global variable for each instance?

Comment: Could you post some sample code? It sounds like you might be better off avoiding global variables, instead using the variable as an argument for the functions and returning the new result at the end.   
You may also want to look at having the variable as a property of the class (self.whatever) instead of being global - that will keep it unique to each class instance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Instance variables vs. class variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714573/instance-variables-vs-class-variables-in-python)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables

Answer (score 1):

You can use method `__init__` for difinition of variables for every instance of class. You can read more information here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-is-difference-between-self-and-init-methods-in-python-Class

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class and you'd like variables to be shared in that class, you can do so in the `__init__` function:

```
class Example:

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def print_a(self):
        print(self.a)

example = Example(a = 5, b = 3)
example.print_a()
```