# Attribute Error: type object 'Object1' has no attribute 'mu'

Tags: python

This is a part of a code

```
class Object1:
    def __init__(self):
        mu = np.linspace(1.65, 1.8, num = 50)
        self.mu=mu
```

I need to call `mu` attribute out of `class`.

What I tried:

```
a=getattr(Object1,'mu')
a=Object1.mu
```

**Edit:** I explain in a better way the problem and the solution.

I apologize for not posting all the code from the beginning, but I can't (I'll post a part of it) and because of that my question was misunderstood, I'll post the solution anyway and ask the question again.

```
import scipy.stats as sts
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp

class Object1:
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Variables and distributions.

        Returns
        -------
        None.

        """
        mu = np.linspace(1.65, 1.8, num = 50)
        self.mu=mu
        uniform_dist = sts.uniform.pdf(mu) + 1 #sneaky advanced note: I'm using the uniform distribution for clarity, but we can also make the beta distribution look completely flat by tweaking alpha and beta!
        self.uniform_dist=uniform_dist
        beta_dist = sts.beta.pdf(mu, 2, 5, loc = 1.65, scale = 0.2) 
        self.beta_dist =beta_dist 

    def normalization(self,distr):
        return distr/distr.sum()
```

How I was calling the attributes:

```
a=Object1.mu
```

then I tried:

```
a=Object1().mu
```

**Explanation:** To call the `normalization()` method, I must call it on an `object`, and not on the `class`. That is what is failing, because when I do `object.method(parameters)`, Python translates it to `Class.method(object, parameters)`, making the object in question become `self` within the method. Calling it like `Class.method(parameters)`, which is what I did, would result in a missing parameter in the call (python can't tell which one and assumes it's `distr`, but actually it was the first one, `self`).

**Solution:**

```
bayesian=Object1()

uniform_distribution=bayesian.uniform_dist
beta_distribution=bayesian.beta_dist

uniform_dist=bayesian.normalization(uniform_distribution)
beta_dist=bayesian.normalization(beta_distribution)
```

Comment: It is an attribute of an instance, not the class itself. You need to read more tutorials to get the concepts of classes and objects

Comment: The class has no attribute `mu`, the error message is right.

Comment: This code only makes sense if you create an instance of `Object1`, rather than trying to act on the class itself.  E.g. `ob = Object1(); a = ob.mu`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714573/instance-variables-vs-class-variables-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mu as a static variable

```
class Object1:
    mu = np.linspace(1.65, 1.8, num = 50)
    
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```